# Access number of major versions using REST API

Tags: rest

I managed to access the fields "EnableVersioning", "EnableMajorVersions" etc. to check whether my sharepoint lists have versioning enabled.

However, I didn't find any XML element that controls the number of major versions to keep.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `SPList.MajorVersionLimit` and `SPList.MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit` is not exposed in CSOM\JSOM\REST SharePoint 2013 interfaces.

Comment: even though client APIs do not expose the same set of properties as SSOM, there is an alternative approach to retrieve those properties as demonstrated in my answer

Answer (score 0):

### How to retrieve List version related properties using SharePoint REST Interface

Client APIs such as REST/API do not expose the same set of properties as SSOM [SPList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.aspx), for example [SPList.MajorVersionLimit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.majorversionlimit%28v=office.15%29.aspx) is not available in client APIs.

But you could consider the following approach:  ([*](http://blog.vgrem.com/2014/11/09/an-alternative-way-of-getting-client-object-properties-using-sharepoint-rest-and-csom-apis/))

- First step is to retrieve List Schema: 
  `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('list title')?$select=schemaXml`
- Then you could extract List properties from `SchemaXml` property

> (*) Follow [An alternative way of getting Client Object properties using SharePoint REST and CSOM APIs](http://blog.vgrem.com/2014/11/09/an-alternative-way-of-getting-client-object-properties-using-sharepoint-rest-and-csom-apis/) for a more details

**Example**

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve `List` version related properties:

```
var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
getListProperties(webUrl,'Documents').done(function(properties){
     console.log(properties.MajorVersionLimit);
     console.log(properties.MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit);
     console.log(properties.EnableVersioning);
     console.log(properties.EnableMinorVersion);
}); 



function getListProperties(webUrl,listTitle)
{
    var endpointUrl = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')?$select=schemaXml";
    return getJson(endpointUrl).then(function(data){
             var listProperties = schemaXml2Json(data.d.SchemaXml);
             return listProperties;
           });
}
```

where

```
function getJson(url) 
{
    return $.ajax({       
       url: url,   
       type: "GET",  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: { 
          "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
       }
    });
}


function schemaXml2Json(schemaXml)
{ 
    var jsonObject = {};
    var schemaXmlDoc = $.parseXML(schemaXml);
    $(schemaXmlDoc).find('List').each(function() {
      $.each(this.attributes, function(i, attr){
           jsonObject[attr.name] = attr.value;
      });
    });
    return jsonObject;
}
```